# how to extract commit patches from a git repository

Tags: git

I would like to extract all patches from a git repository,
or at least all ancestors from a selected tag or commit.

I need each commit as a separate patch. Each patch should end up into its own file. The command can create a directory or a tar archive.

Closest I could find is `git-format-patch`, but it outputs everything as a single patch.

Comment: How are you running `format-patch`? By default it should create a patch file for each commit.

Comment: You are right. For some reasons, in previous tests, patches would either be printed to stdout, or not be generated at all when output was a directory.
However, now I'm getting proper result, with a list of patches ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with `git-format-patch`:

```
git format-patch -o patches --root HEAD
```

It will write patches to `patches` directory. Of course you can replace `HEAD` with sha of particular commit or with some tag.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: using `git format-patch -o path/to/folder`, with intermediate directories `path/to` not yet created,... means the command would fail.

"`git format-patch -o <outdir>`" did an equivalent of "`mkdir <outdir>`", not "`mkdir -p <outdir>`", which is being corrected with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019).

See [commit edefc31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edefc318731f69c3e5354ead9f7505e789562375) (11 Oct 2019) by [Bert Wesarg (`bertwesarg`)](https://github.com/bertwesarg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f1afbb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1afbb063ff86e40caeaee31146f62c7a3c10c57), 18 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edefc318731f69c3e5354ead9f7505e789562375): create leading components of output directory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bert Wesarg</sup>
>
> '`git format-patch -o <outdir>`' did an equivalent of '`mkdir <outdir>`', not '`mkdir -p <outdir>`'.
>
> Avoid the usage of '`adjust_shared_perm`' on the leading directories which may have security implications.
> Achieved by temporarily disabling of '`config.sharedRepository`' like '`git init`' does.

And (still with Git 2.24, Q4 2019):

See [commit 19c29e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19c29e538e48ed50286339b0fdd5e62111a724db) (21 Oct 2019) by [Bert Wesarg (`bertwesarg`)](https://github.com/bertwesarg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c555caa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c555caab7a303109d6c712d757bc4621a3ee0bbd), 24 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`t4014`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19c29e538e48ed50286339b0fdd5e62111a724db): make output-directory tests self-contained
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bert Wesarg</sup>
>
> [As noted by Gábor](https://public-inbox.org/git/20191011144650.GM29845@szeder.dev/), the new tests in [edefc31873](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edefc318731f69c3e5354ead9f7505e789562375) ("`format-patch`: create leading components of output directory", 2019-10-11, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c555caab7a303109d6c712d757bc4621a3ee0bbd) listed in [batch #0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/)) cannot be run independently.
> Fix this.